# Pandas .loc setting with copy warning

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a question on the usage of `.loc`. I couldn't find an explicit answer in the documentation.

Say I have a df like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.random(1000), "B": np.random.random(1000)})
```

I want to create a 1 in a new column if a value in column A is > .1. Using some boolean logic:

```
crit = df['A'] > .1
```

Now, is using `.loc` this way:

```
df['New Column'] = 0
df['New Column'].loc[crit] = 1
```

Any different than:

```
df['New Column'] = 0
df.loc[crit, 'New Column'] = 1
```

Using the first way, I continually get a `SettingWithCopyWarning`, however the values do appear to be changing in the df.

Comment: use the second method as this will always work, the fact the first method worked is no guarantee that it will always work. The first method is what is called chained indexing you are calling a method on something that may or may not be a copy whilst the latter method is more explicit and will work on the view, the warning here is helping you to avoid this so don't ignore!

Comment: The docs on this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: Right, I read those, however the method it isn't immediately clear that the method I was using is actually chaining since the docs show methods 1 and 2, while mine is #3.. a combination of the first two. @EdChum thanks for verifying the first method is in fact chaining!